# Adding feature layer in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

I am trying to add client-side feature graphics to a feature layer in a map with a roadmap baselayer using the following code, but nothing seems to appear on the map:

```
function CreateFeatureLayer()  {
    featureLayer=new FeatureLayer({ 
        source:[],
        objectIdField:"OBJECTID",
        geometryType:"point",
        spatialReference: { wkid: 4326 },
        fields:[ { name:"OBJECTID", type:"oid" }, { name:"name", type:"string" }, { name:"ktypemid", type:"string" }, { name:"kmid", type:"string" }],
        renderer: { type:"simple",  symbol:{ type: "web-style",  styleName: "Esri2DPointSymbolsStyle",  name: "landmark" } },
        popupTemplate: { title: "{Name}"  }
        });

    map.add(featureLayer);

    const data=[{ LATITUDE: 37.6251, LONGITUDE: -119.085, TYPE: "Title",  NAME: "Name" }];

    let graphics=[];
    let i=0,graphic;
    for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        graphic=new Graphic({
            geometry: { type: "point", latitude: data[i].LATITUDE, longitude: data[i].LONGITUDE },
            attributes: data[i]
            });
        graphics.push(graphic);
        }

    app.featureLayer.applyEdits(graphics);
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, after modeling an example. I also want to be able to use my own bitmap, rather than an ESRI icon.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use a GraphicsLayer, not a FeatureLayer:
Here's what worked:

```
    gl=new GraphicsLayer();  
    map.add(gl);                                        

    function AddPopovers(data) {                                                                
        let i,graphic;
        for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {                                                           // For each element
            graphic=new Graphic({                                                               // Addloc new graphic
                geometry:{ type: "point", latitude:data[i].lat, longitude:data[i].lon },        // Position
                symbol:{ type: "picture-marker", url:"popover.png", width:19, height:13 },      // Shape
                attributes:data[i]                                                              // Raw data
            });
            gl.add(graphic);                                                                
    }       
}
```